# Ionic Angular - how to convert a timestamp to a simple date format

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic-framework

In my ionic project I'm currently seeing the error:

```
 ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous 
 value: 'model: Timestamp(seconds=1584885600, nanoseconds=0)'. Current value: 'model: 2020-03- 
 22T14:00:34.429-00:00'.
```

How do I convert the 'Previous value' to a format that looks like the 'Current value' above.

Comment: if you are using firebase here, you can simply use .toDate() funtion on this timestamp to get js date alternative.

Comment: @Indrajeet when I do that I get a similar error

ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'model: Sun Mar 22 2020 14:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)'. Current value: 'model: 2020-03-22T14:00:34.429-00:00'.

Comment: ohh, that's fine it has to do with the angular lifecycle hook, if you do this conversion in ngAfterContentChecked() instead of ngOnInit() it won't show the error. just implement the  AfterContentChecked in your component class.

Comment: Let me know what happens after that

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880627/12917651